# How to zoom out of WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView in my swift app. I load the URL, but it has a map website in website. When I show it on the app, I have to pinch to zoom out to get it to be at the desired zoom for my to see the entire route. I am trying to figure out how to zoom out with code, so that I can just cause it to pinch zoom out once the url is loaded, and I don't need to keep manually zooming out by pinching.

Comment: Most map sites let you put the zoom factor into the URL as a query parameter. For example here's Boston from "pretty high up" https://www.google.com/maps/@42.3557817,-71.0597593,12.34z, and here's it more zoomed in: https://www.google.com/maps/@42.3528393,-71.0626792,18.11z. Notice the difference? 12.34z vs. 18.11z. What site are you loading, that'll help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

```
    let contentSize = objWebview.scrollView.contentSize
    let viewSize = objWebview.bounds.size

    let rw = Float(viewSize.width / contentSize.width)

    objWebview.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = CGFloat(rw)
    objWebview.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = CGFloat(rw)
    objWebview.scrollView.zoomScale = CGFloat(rw)
    
}
```